# Is my use of global variables in this threaded python script good practice?

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I'm working on an assignment that uses threading, and I use global variables to take care of the problems I was having (like sharing variables between threads). I know using global variables is generally discouraged, so I wanted to ask if this is an appropriate use of global variables.

Here's the code. You'll find the global variables declared in function1() and function2().

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import random
import Queue


def getNextPrime(num):
    flag = False
    while(flag == False):
        num = num + 1
        flag = True
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                flag = False
                break

    # if we get here num should equal our next prime
    return num


def function1(self):
    i = 100
    global output_buffer
    output_buffer = Queue.Queue()
    while True:
        output_buffer.put("Thread 1: " + str(i))
        i -= 1
        sleep(1)


def function2(self):
    while True:
        global rand_num
        rand_num = random.randrange(4, 99999)
        output_buffer.put("Thread 2: " + str(rand_num))
        sleep(1)


def function3(self):
    while True:
        output_buffer.put("Thread 3: " + str(rand_num / 2.5))
        sleep(1)


def function4(self):
    prime_num = 1
    for i in range(0, 20):
        output_buffer.put("Thread 4: " + str(prime_num))
        prime_num = getNextPrime(prime_num)
        sleep(1)

# if I don't handle output like this I get weird behavior like two threads printing on the same line
def buffer_dump(self):
    while True:
        while not output_buffer.empty():
            print output_buffer.get()
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    random.seed()
    thread1 = Thread(target=function1, args=(1, ))
    thread2 = Thread(target=function2, args=(1, ))
    thread3 = Thread(target=function3, args=(1, ))
    thread4 = Thread(target=function4, args=(1, ))
    output_thread = Thread(target=buffer_dump, args=(1, ))

    thread1.start()
    output_thread.start()
    sleep(2)
    thread2.start()
    sleep(2)
    thread3.start()
    sleep(2)
    thread4.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the global variables well. However, your code could even be more readable if you move the two global variables outside your functions. It will not affect their scope. You can read this Faq on global variables too here,

https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Comment: Just tried that, I get `NameError: [var] not defined` when my threads start. I also tried initializing them in the main block and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I see the problem. Python does not allow for variable declarations and innitialisations on different lines. Declare and initialise all variables on the same line like this,

```
rand_num = random.randrange(4, 99999)
```

and not like this,

```
global rand_num
    rand_num = random.randrange(4, 99999)
```

Remove the global keyword from all your variables. Then place all variables with the global keyword outside all your function definitions

Comment: So I played around with it a little bit. I was about to avoid declaring my output buffer as a global variable, but not 'rand_num'. What would happen is the assignment of 'rand_num' in function2 wouldn't update that variable when it's used in function3. If I really wanted to avoid global variables I could just declare a Rand_num class with getters and setters. I think I might do that.